# Automate file replacement

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have a task to rename a file and place another file with same name in the same folder

Like for e.g. a folder `C:/test` I have multiple files `.txt` (suppose `test.txt` is the one needed rename and replace)
I want to rename `test.txt` to `test_bkp%date%` and place new file there.
Need help to start the logic.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\test\new"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%C:\Users\Test\new\%filenames%.txt" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
  ECHO REN "%C:\Users\Test\new\%%a C:\Users\Test\new\%%a_bk_date.*%"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I get file with updated data often. I cannot just go ahead and replace the old file with new. I have to take a backup and place the new file in the folder. 
This is my first try using batch scripting

Comment: use a `for` loop, look at the `for` loop help (command line and/or web) ? something like `FOR %%G IN (*.txt) DO rename %%G  test_bk%date%`

Comment: I tried but this should be automated  .another person put a file in different location i move it to the current location and have to rename the existing file and place the new file (its like updating the file with new /additional data)

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the code you are trying to make work. Tell what it is doing and what it should do.

Comment: What's the content of `%filenames%`? `Ren` destination is filename.ext only (no path). Your `ren` command has only one parameter (watch your quotes).

Comment: thank you.. I might be lame ..I am new to this and want to give a try. the above one is what i tried by googling ... on x system we rehave files with some configuration data. so we get constant updates and request to replace those files. So assume we have 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt. and recieved an updated file 1.txt. i am trying to automate the process to lto find the file with the name 1.txt and take a copy of it and then replace it with new file.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you write a new version of a file into the same folder than the original (with the same name), it's already too late to rename the original - it doesn't exist anymore. You need two folders: one that receives new versions (`new`) and one where you keep your renamed files plus the new ones (`old`)

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
set "source=C:\Users\test\new"
set "destin=C:\Users\test\old"
set "files=*.txt"

REM for every matching file in the source folder:
for %%A in ("%source%\%files%") do (
  REM if there is such a file in the destination folder, rename it:
  if exist "%destin%\%%~nxA" ren "%destin%\%%~nxA" "%%~nA-%date%%%~xA"
  REM only then copy the file:
  copy "%%~fA" "%destin%\"
)
```

This will fail if you run it more than once per day. (More code needed to handle that; for example, adding `time` too)
It will also fail if your `%date%` contains characters that are not allowed in file names (my `%date%` looks like `29.01.2019`). (More code needed to handle that; for example `%date:/=-%`)

Comment: thanks stephan..here is what my plan is .. move the file to different folder-->extract file name to txt file--> use for to identify that file int he folder and move it to backup folder by adding date format--> then move the incoming file to that folder. need to figure out the for /r to look in to a txt for the file name